# Error installing Exchange2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

I was trying to install Exchange Server 2016 on Windows Server 2016, everything was going smoothly. But, unfortunately someone switched off my Machine where I have installed Virtual Box and running both AD and Exchange installation. It as in the process of installing Roles (5/14). When i started the setup again I am getting the below error.

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
$roleList = $RoleRoles.Replace('Role','').Split(',');
if($roleList -contains 'LanguagePacks')
{
& $RoleBinPath\ServiceControl.ps1 Save
& $RoleBinPath\ServiceControl.ps1 DisableServices $roleList;
& $RoleBinPath\ServiceControl.ps1 Stop $roleList;
};
" was run: "System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Reverse" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: array" ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: array
at System.Array.Reverse(Array array)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception exception, Type typeToThrow, String methodName, Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo memberInfo)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)".
```

Could you please help.

Comment: Might be more safe to use a system restore point before the installation of these new roles started.

Comment: Just as an idea, please check if all Exchange Services are disabled before you try the 2nd install. Based on the error I think he is trying to stop some services which he expect to be running but failed.

Answer (score 1):

As it seem a lab on virtualbox I would simply redo the VM from stracht, as it will be faster than trying to debug the issue.